# Why does my EditText not save its State (mostly its Text)?

Tags: android, android-edittext, fragment, android-lifecycle, android-orientation

So EditTexts should save their Text when changing orientation.
In this particular Fragment, they dont. Why is that?

my Fragment:

```
 public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * @param inflater
     * @param container
     * @param savedInstanceState
     * @return
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,
     *      android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onStart()
     */
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    getView().findViewById(R.id.login_ok).setOnClickListener(
        new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),
                StartActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My edittexts in xml:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner"
        android:ems="10"

        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>





    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_pw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner"
        android:ems="10"

        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="8dp" />
```

This is the onCreate Method of my Activity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.login_frame, new LoginFragment());
ft.commit();`
```

Comment: How is the fragment being added to the activity?

Comment: first i declared it in xml, but now ive also tried to add it in the code onto a frame Layout. Ill post the code in a sec as a edit on my question.

Comment: I believe it should be pretty seamless if the fragment is added in the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I had this problem, because i added my Fragment with a FragmentTransaction into a FrameLayout(which had a unique ID).

Now I've declared my Fragment once again in the XML with a unique ID and it works.

I cant really explain why it wont work when adding it with a FragmentTransaction, if the container has an unique ID, but atleast it works now.

Comment: I guess it's Because you create a NEW Fragment every time with the FM.

Answer (score 1):

The Activity gets recreated when the orientation changes, that's right.
However, it is not neccessary to handle the UI elements' state:

> Almost every widget in the Android framework implements this method as appropriate, such that any visible changes to the UI are automatically saved and restored when your activity is recreated. For example, the EditText widget saves any text entered by the user and the CheckBox widget saves whether it's checked or not. The only work required by you is to provide a unique ID (with the android:id attribute) for each widget you want to save its state. If a widget does not have an ID, then the system cannot save its state.

From:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState

**Note:** If you want to preserve the EditText Value, even when the user uses the BACK button, you need a persistenet storage. onSaveInstanceState will not be called.

Here's a simple example (EditText value preserved):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acitivty_main); 
    }
}


public class EditFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit, container);
    }
}
```

The .XML file

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_id"
    android:name="com.example.fragementtest.EditFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In this particular Instance, the Edittexts values are not saved, even though in another Activity the text is saved with no problem. Maybe because these Edittexts have hints? I've created a workaround with `setRetainInstance(true)` and saving the Text in a class variable but thats pretty ugly.

Comment: You should better find the cause for that issue.
I guess it's the log on screen, you are talking about. Are you sure, you are not navigating back with the back button? Try to "switch" the application instead of closing it and see if the instant state works then. Or you are probbably  overwriting your EditText somewhere again?

Comment: i agree, i should find out why they dont behave like they should. i have updated my question. everything is back to slim, and these texts SHOULD save. but they dont. Im just switching between portrait and landscape mode and the edittexts are empty again.

Comment: Check out my example above, it works (just tested on my device).
Your error must be somewhere else. Take the example code and add your custom code step by step.

Comment: Thanks, but ive already found a solution that works atleast for this Fragment. See my Answer. Have a good week :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to make sure your TextEdit and TextView fields preserve their contents is to set their freezesText attribute.